# Spark view engine not changing output when partial altered

Tags: spark-view-engine

I have an issue that I'm trying to diagnose with the spark view engine. For some reason when I change a partial template the output isn't being altered. Its like its been stashed somewhere. I've tried resetting IIS and deleting the .NET temporary files directory but it still doesn't seem to be noticing the changes.

I've even tried deleting the partial file to see if I can break it, but it still pulls in the same markup. Very frustrating.

I had a look in the cs file that is being built to render the view and the file reference for the partial is the one that I'm changing. So I'm sure that I'm not messing with the wrong file. I've tried re-cloning the project but still no change.

I really have no idea how this can be happening, I've tried having a look through the spark code to see if I can see anything obvious but it all points to any temporary files being stashed in the same place, and I've deleted that so back to square one.

Any help would be appreciated on this as I'm starting to doubt my sanity.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the the answer was make sure you look at files that aren't shown in the solution. At some point files had been coped but not deleted so there was another version of the partial kicking around.